# Can't get RestSharp to work with DELETE and RequestBody

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, restsharp

I send a DELETE request with a request body, with these parameters:
[image]

The server responds with status 500. I do

```
curl -D- -X DELETE -d "{\"pin\":\"1111\"}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Basic sameasinimagabove" https://myrestapiendpoint/resource/id
```

and it works. I use the latest version of RestSharp.WindowsPhone v. 104.3.3.0.
What could be wrong? 
Code for building and sending the request:

```
    RestRequest PrepareRequest(Method method, string url, IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(url, method);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + "yadyadyadyada");
        request.AddHeader("X-Originator-Type", "app");
        request.AddHeader("X-Os-Type", Environment.OSVersion.Platform.ToString());
        request.AddHeader("X-Os-Version", Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString());
        request.AddHeader("X-Device-Id", AppUtil.DeviceId);
        request.AddHeader("X-Client-Version", AppUtil.ApplicationVersion);
        request.AddHeader("Locale", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
        request.AddHeader("If-Modified-Since", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u"));
        if (data != null || method == Method.PUT || method == Method.POST || method == Method.DELETE)
        {
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            if (data == null)
                data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            string json = JsonParser.Serialize(data);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        }
    }

    _restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                     {
                         _activeRequests.Remove(handle);
                         done(responseHandler(AddRequestToResponse(request, response)));
                     });
```

Comment: Can you show your code (that uses RestSharp) which is building/executing the request?

Comment: Added some code showing building request and sending it.

Comment: I suspect that it is not failing how you think it is. I believe that the BODY _is_ being included in your request; can you verify (using Fiddler, etc.), that your request is indeed missing it's body? I suspect that the actual cause of your 500 is that your data is being double-serialized. I will post an answer explaining this suspicion in more detail and how you can fix it.

Comment: Nice thanks! (I've searched the webs on how to use fiddler with RestSharp but haven't found a good way to do it. Do you have a description of how to do it?)

Comment: I use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and let it run in the background to capture all traffic to/from my machine (says "Capturing" in the bottom-left of the UI). Then I just run the code that does the REST request. You should see the request appear in the list on the left. Double-click on the request to inspect it, then click on the "Raw" view in the Inspector window to see a plain-text view of the request (headers and body).

Comment: Aha cool, I thought you'd have to configure RestSharp to go through a proxy of some sort to have fiddler pick it up. Anyway, fiddler shows nothing in the JSON view and in the Raw view Content-Length: 0

Answer (score 2):

There was [a bug in RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/399) that previously prevented you from being able to send any Body content as part of a DELETE request. This bug has been fixed as of [version 104.2.0 of RestSharp](http://haacked.com/archive/2013/09/18/restsharp-104-2-0-released.aspx).

Here is an example of some code that Un-pins a build using TeamCity's REST API:

```
public void UnpinBuild(int buildId, string comment = null)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("builds/id:{id}/pin", Method.DELETE);
    request.AddUrlSegment("id", "" + buildId);
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comment))
    {
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", comment, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Executing '{0}' request to '{1}'...", request.Method, _restClient.BuildUri(request));
    var response = _restClient.Execute(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        throw new Exception("Build does not exist for ID: " + buildId);
    }
    CheckForError(response);
    CheckForExpectedStatusCode(response, HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

The key part of that code is this line:

```
request.AddParameter("text/plain", comment, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

That line adds the request body and does a few other related things, e.g. sets the "Content-Length" header correctly.

Comment: Thing is I'm using version 104.3.3.0 so it should include the above mentioned fix.

Comment: I know you are on the newest version of RestSharp and this answer won't likely help you specifically but I posted it for everyone else. Anyone who is on an older version of RestSharp and having troubles using DELETE with a body will Google for it, see this Q&A, and hopefully realize that they just need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You may have uncovered a bug in RestSharp.

I tried running your code (slightly simplified) on my Windows 7 machine and it seems to work.

```
var restClient = new RestClient("http://api.example.com");
var restRequest = new RestRequest("myResource", Method.DELETE);

restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + "yadyadyadyada");
restRequest.AddHeader("X-Originator-Type", "app");
restRequest.AddHeader("X-Os-Type", Environment.OSVersion.Platform.ToString());
restRequest.AddHeader("X-Os-Version", Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString());
restRequest.AddHeader("X-Device-Id", "myDeviceID");
restRequest.AddHeader("X-Client-Version", "1.2.3");
restRequest.AddHeader("Locale", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
restRequest.AddHeader("If-Modified-Since", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u"));

var data = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" }, };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

When run, Fiddler shows that the request has a body:

[image: Fiddler screen-capture]

This seems to work properly on a regular Windows machine. Unfortunately, I don't have a Windows Phone to test on. I would suggest you try the code on a regular Windows machine and a Windows Phone and see if you get different results.

Comment: Seems as if it works for RestClient.Execute but not for RestClient.ExecuteAsync, see https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/424#issuecomment-27893716